# Script error occured while using marketo "munchkin" api script

Tags: javascript, tracking

I want to implement Marketo tracking visitor in my website. For that I have logged in into Marketo. I got some code, and I pasted it on the footer.php. But I am getting script error on the console.

> TypeError: a is undefined

This is my code

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + document.location.protocol +

  "//munchkin.marketo.net/munchkin.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));

</script>

<script>Munchkin.init('My Id');</script>
```

What is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

After debugging the munchkin.js, I could figure out that it is making a call to $.browser which has been deprecated in jquery 1.9.

http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#jquery-browser-removed

To resolve this issue, I used the jquery migrate script to include the $.browser method.
All I needed to do was to include the migrate script just below the jquery script include tag

https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/#readme

Hope that helps.